# Using viewholder with cursor adapter

Tags: android, cursor, android-view, android-cursoradapter

I'm searching for a proper tutorial on how to use the viewholders along with cursor adapter.

Mostly all tutorials are provided for ArrayAdapter.If the same is adopted for cursor adapter it is bit messy.

can anyone explain the same.

thanks in advance.

Comment: SimpleCursorAdapter is not enough?

Comment: @siva You want to know how to use View Holder for Cursor Adapter?

Comment: @Venky yes i need to know that

Comment: @Selvin SimpleCursorAdapter is not suitable for me.Because i have to make join two cursor and it becomes costly

Comment: @siva so question is not clear ... you should ask how can u optimize code using Viewholders and you should show what you have already  ...

Comment: @Selvin yes, i should have clearly explained

Comment: @siva just put your getView code here and maybe some one will help you

Comment: Same issue for me.  Would love to see some tutorial or a simple explanation.  From what I *think* I understand, ViewHolder is not necessary CursorAdapters.  But I want to see someone who really understands say that, as I suspect I'm wrong.